# An empty JSON field which is a boolean/nullable field in Java model, is getting converted as null

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a specific requirement where in,

- if a (boolean type) field in the request `JSON` body is absent altogether, then the request is valid.
- If this field is set with a boolean value (`true` or `false`), then it is obviously valid.
- If the field has non-boolean values, it should throw an exception.
- If the field has **empty** value, **it should throw an exception**.

Even though the `Java` model throws an exception if the field is non-boolean by type checking, **the empty value is being converted as null**. Instead I need to be able to distinguish it and throw an exception. How can achieve this?

Here's how I defined the post body model and I am using the AutoValue generator so I don't have the setter function for the fields written by hand. Also, I am using the fasterxml library.

```
@JsonProperty("indicator")
@Nullable
public abstract Boolean getIndicator();
```

I have tried defining a custom annotation and writing the logic to check if the value is empty, but it didn't work.

Comment: Treating empty value as null is a feature of the JSON parser you're using. Since we don't know which JSON parser you use, we can't really help figure out how to re-configure it to not treat empty as null, now can we?

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks for your response. I am using **fasterxml** library as JSON parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable [MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS) feature which allows coercion in cases like you have. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"indicator\":\"\"}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, BaseClass.class));
    }
}

class BaseClass {
    private Boolean indicator;

    public Boolean getIndicator() {
        return indicator;
    }

    public void setIndicator(Boolean indicator) {
        this.indicator = indicator;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BaseClass{" +
                "indicator=" + indicator +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   coerce empty String ("") to Null value for type `java.lang.Boolean`
>   (enable `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS` to allow)  at
>   [Source: (String)"{"indicator":""}"; line: 1, column: 14] (through
>   reference chain: BaseClass["indicator"])